# How to convert TargetLink model to Simulink

Tags: c, matlab, model, simulink, dspace-ecu

I'm new to Targetlink and need to convert Targetlink blocks to simulink blocks. Do I need Targetlink license for converting as well ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

open the targetlink main dialog, in Tools tab, just click Clear System. It will remove every TL block from you model, then you can get the SL model

Answer (score 1):

After TargetLink 3.0 all the TL blocks are Simulink blocks with TargetLink masks over them.

You shall be able to run such a TL model in Simulink after installation of a free TargetLink-Standalone software which you can request from dSpace.

For de-enhancing TargetLink you also need a TargetLink installation with a valid license.

If the model is not too big, you can remove all TL block masks by hand in 2 steps without using TargetLink at all:

1. Right click on block->Mask->Edit Mask->Unmask;
2. Right click on block->Properties...->Callbacks->remove content of all Callback functions with asterix "*", f.e. CopyFcn, DeleteFcn etc.

You also can write a MATLAB script to automate the above 2-step process.

**Note:** Be aware that the TargetLink-Code behaves not exactly like Simulink model. So you will need to verify it in a back-to-back test.